# What character is that HTML entity?

Tags: code-golf, parsing

The goal is really simple. Receiving a string as input, parse all the HTML entities that correspond to the following characters (including their uppercase variants):

```
áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüýÿ
```

Parsing rules:

- Each entity starts with `&` and ends with `;`
- The first character after the `&` will be the modified character (letter case is important!)
- The remaining characters refer to the name of the accent to use (`acute`, `grave`, `circ`, `tilde` and `uml`). The accent name **MUST** be in lowercase! *
- Any HTML entity that produces a character that isn't on that list, or that is invalid, should be left untouched (E.g.: `&amp;`, `&etilde;`, `&a;`)
- Numeric entities should be ignored, since they don't fit in the rules above

<sub>This change was introduced as of 18-02-2016. All the existing answers that accept HTML entities with uppercase accent names are valid. Any future answer must follow this rule.</sub>

**Examples:**

```
&aacute; //á
T&eacute;h&egrave;h //Téhèh
an &amp; //an &amp;
```

**Output:**

The output can be in ISO-8859-*X* (1-15), windows-1252 or UTF-8/16/32.
You can pick **one and only one** of the valid encodings and use it for **any** output. You can safely assume that the input will be in ASCII.

Any of the following is a valid output for `&aacute;`:

- `á` (ISO-8859-1/15 or windows-1252, equivalent to `\xE1`)
- `Ã¡` (UTF-8, equivalent to `\xC3\xA1` or `\u00E1`)
- `aÌ` (UTF-8, equivalent to `a\xCC\x81` or `a\u0301`)
- Any combination of diacritics, without using HTML entities.

The output has to be visually similar, when rendered/displayed, to the characters on the list.

---

Remember, all the standard loopholes *and built-ins* * are **disallowed**. Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer wins.

<sub>* This change was made due to the great disapproval of bonuses and penalities, and at the time of writting, doesn't invalidate any answer</sub>

Comment: I didn't vote, but I assume the downvotes are because people don't really like bonuses/penalties - They end up making one challenge into several mini-challenges.

Comment: +1 I like this challenge. But about the sandbox ... I never visit it and probably never will. Surely many other users do the same

Comment: @KevinW. As I explained in the sandbox, I only left those penalities because I want to see what cool built-in stuff people can come up with. But obviously, I don't want to spoil everybody's fun. If I didn't put the penality, an answer like the Javascript example I gave, would be enough. And that required no work at all.

Comment: @edc65 Thank you a lot for the vote. If you see something wrong, you can comment here. I will try my hardest to fix every tiny little thingy. I've made it thinking that more people would find it fun. I guess I was wrong. But 4 persons is better than 0, right?

Comment: IMHO, the bonuses seem arbitrary - either allow or don't allow, don't go in between.

Comment: @VoteToClose Which bonus would you use? I'm still open to suggestions, since no one went for them.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I suggest no bonuses/penalties - allow whatever programming methods they wish to use (outside of the Standard Loopholes, of course) and remove the bonuses/penalties.

Comment: @VoteToClose Done. Any more changes?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Nah - that was all of my cents. c:

Comment: If we choose the third option for encoding the accents, *all* of them will show up as `Ì` (although each with a different trailing unprintable). I'm guessing we must output the unprintable as well?

Comment: @ETHproductions Yes, it is part of the sequence. The important is that, whatever you pick, produces the right character on the allowed encodings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Japt, <s>81</s> 75 bytes

```
Ur`&([%vYy](ac©e|uml)|%v(g?ve|circ)|[AaOo]Èìe);`@Yg +'Ì+"?????"g"gutca"bYgJ
```

The six `?`s represent unprintable chars. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VXJgJihbJXZZeV0oYWOpZXx1bWwpfCV2KGefdmV8Y2lyYyl8W0FhT29dyOxlKTtgQFlnICsnzCsigIGCg4giZyJndXRjYSJiWWdK&input=IlQmZWFjdXRlO2gmZWdyYXZlO2gi)

Note: This outputs the third encoding option; that is, the letter followed by the raw UTF-8 encoding of the corresponding combining diacritical mark.

#### How it works

```
Ur"&(    );"       // Replace each ampersand and semicolon that have one of these between them:
([%vYy](acute|uml) //  A vowel or Yy followed by "acute" or "uml",
|%v(grave|circ)    //  or a vowel followed by "grave" or "circ",
|[AaOo]tilde       //  or "a" or "o" followed by "tilde";
@                  // replace each match X and its middle Y with this function:
""g"gutca"bYgJ     //  Take the unprintable at index (index of the second char in Y in "gutca") in this string.
Yg +'Ì+            //  Concatenate the first char in Y and "Ì" to the beginning.
                   // Implicit output
```

Hexdump of the code:

```
00000000: 55 72 60 26 28 5b 25 76 59 79 5d 28 61 63 a9 65  Ur`&([%vYy](ac©e
00000010: 7c 75 6d 6c 29 7c 25 76 28 67 9f 76 65 7c 63 69  |uml)|%v(g.ve|ci
00000020: 72 63 29 7c 5b 41 61 4f 6f 5d c8 ec 65 29 3b 60  rc)|[AaOo]Èìe);`
00000030: 40 59 67 20 2b 27 cc 2b 22 80 81 82 83 88 22 67  @Yg +'Ì+"....."g
00000040: 22 67 75 74 63 61 22 62 59 67 4a                 "gutca"bYgJ
```

Comment: It seems to work nicely. Can you please provide a hexdump? You seem to have there some "weird" characters that may not work in every encoding.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I've just realized that the accents are not part of the ISO-8859-1 encoding; thus, I've uncompressed the string and switched to UTF-8 bytes. Would you still like a hexdump?

Comment: Up to you, but your previous solution was perfectly fine.

Comment: I think you might have a tiny bug there, your code seems to leave `&Yacute;` alone, but it should be changed to Ý...

Comment: @daavko Whoops, you're right! Fixed now.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>141</s> <s>122</s> 134 bytes

```js
a=>a.replace(/&([aeiouyAEIOUY](acute|uml)|[aeiouAEIOU](grave|circ)|[aoAO]tilde);/g,b=>b[1]+{g:"̀",a:"́",c:"̂",t:"̃",u:"̈"}[b[2]])
```

Followed daavko's example using diacritical marks, and I feel like an idiot for not thinking of using it sooner. Actually gets surprisingly short for JavaScript.

EDIT: Neil caught some bad cases of undefined, which are now fixed.

Comment: See? I told you that you could cut some fat! This is a really surprising answer! I trully hope you get more +1's

Comment: This is just clever. +1

Comment: I love it..! `String.prototype.replace` is so ridiculously golfable for string traversal.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this does the right thing for `&EACUTE;` (whatever that right thing is).

Comment: Sadly, @Neil is right. Uppercase HTML entities are considered invalid by browsers. But, I didn't specify that the accent name should be all in lowercase. That is entirelly my fault. I will consider this answer valid and all the ones that were already posted. But any new answer must have the accent names in lowercase.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Given that it returns `Eundefined` in the above case, you might want to reconsider whether the answer is valid...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Indeed, I don't want to be an exception; I just didn't catch that situation. I'll fix it up.

Comment: @Neil In that case, it was invalid. But the answer is not fixed.

Comment: @Mwr247 You aren't the exception. daavko's answer is working the same way, accepting `&AACUTE;` as a valid input.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I can fix that, if needed.

Comment: I don't know Retina but I don't see @daavko's answer having the same problem as this one.

Comment: @Neil it does have the same problem. It matches `&AACUTE;` and other uppercase entites. I've added a new version, which complies with the rule.

Comment: @daavko No, that's a different problem. Mine would return `Eundefined` for `&EACUTE;`, while yours would do the special character as though it was lowercase. Yours would be valid per the exception, mine would not, as mine was an error.

Comment: @daavko No, it isn't needed. Your answer is valid. I would have accepted the old version of this answer if it didn't returned `Eundefined` instead of `É`. Other than that, there's nothing wrong with this answer or yours.

Answer (score 10):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 115 bytes

I'm new to code-golf, but I think this might work.
This version was made before the rule, which doesn't allow replacing uppercase html entities (for example `&AACUTE;`) was introduced.

```
i`&([aeiouy])acute;
$1́
i`&([aeiou])grave;
$1̀
i`&([ao])tilde;
$1̃
i`&([aeiou])circ;
$1̂
i`&([aeiouy])uml;
$1̈
```

Quite simple search and replace. Uses UTF-8.

Uses [letter]\xCC\x[diacritical mark hex code] approach. Diacritical mark is added after every relevant letter.

For some reason, the default Droid Sans Mono font in the interpreter can't render the "circ" and "uml" letters properly. If you change it through developer tools to something like DejaVu Sans, it shows just fine. I think this is a limitation of the font, not the program. But if it's program's fault, I'll try to fix it.

Here is a 129 byte version, which doesn't replace uppercase HTML entites (for example `&AACUTE;`)

```
&([aeiouyAEIOUY])acute;
$1́
&([aeiouAEIOU])grave;
$1̀
&([aoAO])tilde;
$1̃
&([aeiouAEIOU])circ;
$1̂
&([aeiouyAEIOUY])uml;
$1̈
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=aWAmKFthZWlvdXldKWFjdXRlOwokMcyBCmlgJihbYWVpb3VdKWdyYXZlOwokMcyACmlgJihbYW9dKXRpbGRlOwokMcyDCmlgJihbYWVpb3VdKWNpcmM7CiQxzIIKaWAmKFthZWlvdXldKXVtbDsKJDHMiA&input=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)
[Try it online! 129-byte version](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JihbYWVpb3V5QUVJT1VZXSlhY3V0ZTsKJDHMgQomKFthZWlvdUFFSU9VXSlncmF2ZTsKJDHMgAomKFthb0FPXSl0aWxkZTsKJDHMgwomKFthZWlvdUFFSU9VXSljaXJjOwokMcyCCiYoW2FlaW91eUFFSU9VWV0pdW1sOwokMcyI&input=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)

Comment: Great use of the marks there. Can't believe I didn't think of that being shorter at first >_<

Comment: @Mwr247 Thanks! I was searching for a way to do this, since I wanted to try to do it and the marks just showed up somewhere...I'm honestly surprised it's so short.

Comment: Nice fair-play and use of the rules! I never liked this language, but I really am loving this answer. Instant +1

Comment: I counted 115 bytes (110 characters + 5 extra bytes for the marks).

Comment: @Mwr247 Oh, you're right. I just pasted it into a text document and ran ls -l and it showed 116...seems the editor added an extra newline at the end. I'll fix it.

Comment: Notice that your answer accepts HTML entities that are invalid, for example `&EACUTE;`. The rule was changed today, but your answer is still valid. I just wanted to point this out, in case you write a new answer that works that way. The new answer would be invalid, but this one I consider valid.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I've added a new version, which complies with the new rule.

Comment: @daavko It wasn't needed. But since you added the new version, just state that the "main" version was made before the rule.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 288 bytes

```js
a=>(z=(b,c=1,d=2,e=3,f=0,g=4)=>({b:b+191,grave:c,acute:d,circ:e,tilde:f,uml:g}),y={a:z(0,1,2,3,4,5),e:z(8),i:z(12),o:z(18,1,2,3,4,5),u:z(25),y:z(28,0,2,0)},a.replace(/&\w+;/gi,b=>(x=y[b[1].toLowerCase()])&&(w=x[b.slice(2,-1)])?String.fromCharCode(x.b+w+32*(b[1]>'_')+153*/Yu/.test(b)):b))
```

Creates a character map object (with the base numeric code for each character), and uses offsets (or 0 if non-existent) to determine if an entity should be converted and what it's character code is. Symmetry in the cases means adding 32 if lowercase, except for `&Yuml;`, where it uses a different offset for UTF8.

Comment: Nice! I really like your aproach, but 286 bytes is a bit long. Maybe there are a few things that can be cut off? Trimming some fat would be great

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel 288 actually; I just realized that there is in fact a `&Yuml;` in UTF8: it's just in a weird place. All the same, I thought I condensed and optimized it rather well, considering a literal replace list would be over twice as long. Are you seeing something I'm not?

Comment: Not really... There must be a better way to make lowercase letters than using `.toLowerCase()`. That name is HUGE!!! Also, `String.fromCharCode` can accept multiple parameters, or be called as `String.fromCharCode.call([...])`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel JavaScript's verboseness FTL as usual haha... I've tried removing the `toLowerCase` and related stuffs, but it requires me to map every uppercase value as well, which even when optimized still comes out over 300 characters. `String.fromCharCode` with multiple parameters doesn't really help either, since I only need to convert to a single character at a time, and the regex replace handles any repetition, so it's only written out once as is. If this can be made significantly shorter, it'll have to be a total rewrite, and probably done by someone better than me ;)

Comment: Well, you already did an amazing job at it. I know that, on PHP, you can do `A^' '` to convert to lowercase. In Javascript, don't know any shorter way :/

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Seems I was right about it needing a rewrite, but wrong about it needing to be someone else. I feel this answer is more interesting, but the other one is technically more concise, so I've included them both separately.

Comment: Not life-changing but your regexp contains no literal letters so it doesn't need the `i` flag.

Comment: @Neil I wasn't expecting that to work! Running ``/\w/.test`A`;`` confirms that you are right. Holy cow! I've learned something today.